# A variation on $k(x^2,x^3)=k(x)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, fields, resultants

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, for example $k=\mathbb{R}$ or $k=\mathbb{C}$.

Of course, $k(x^2,x^3)=k(x)$, since $x=\frac{x^3}{x^2}$.

Let $f_1,\ldots,f_n,g_1,\ldots,g_m \in k[x]$, $n,m \geq 1$.

Denote: $F(T)=f_nT^n+\cdots+f_1T+x^2$
and $G(T)=g_mT^m+\cdots+g_1T+x^3$.

Let $h \in k[x]$.

> Is it possible to characterize
> $f_1,\ldots,f_n,g_1,\ldots,g_m \in k[x]$, $n,m \geq 1$,
> such that for *every* $h \in k[x]$ we have: $k(F(h),G(h))=k(x)$?

I could not find such $f_i,g_j,n,m$.

**For example:**
$F(T)=T+x^2$, $G(T)=T+x^3$.
For $h=x^3$ we get $F(h)=x^3+x^2$, $G(h)=x^3+x^3=2x^3$,
so clearly, $k(F(h),G(h))=k(x)$.
For $h=x^4-x^3$ we get $F(h)=x^4-x^3+x^2$, $G(h)=x^4-x^3+x^3=x^4$,
abd then, $k(F(h),G(h)) \subsetneq k(x)$.

I think that for arbitrary fixed $f_i,g_j,n,m$, there exists $h \in k[x]$ such that
$k(F(h),G(h)) \subsetneq k(x)$, but not sure how to prove this.

I am familiar with D-resultant, but it seems difficult to apply it.
The theorem relevant here is that
$D-\operatorname{Res_s}(\frac{(F(h))(s)-F(h)}{s-x},\frac{(G(h))(s)-G(h)}{s-x})$
is a non-zero element of $k[x]$ if and only if $k(F(h),G(h))=k(x)$.
See [this paper](https://www.academia.edu/29672226/Jacobian_pairs_D_resultants_and_automorphisms_of_the_plane).

If we apply this to $x^2,x^3$ we obtain that their D-resultant is $x^2$, and indeed
$k(x^2,x^3)=k(x)$.

Also, I wonder if algebraic geometry could help solve my question.

**In addition:**
**(1)** I do not mind to further assume that for every $h \in k$,
$k(F(h),G(h)) = k(x)$.
In the above example, this is satisfied.
**(2)** $f_1,\ldots,f_n,g_1,\ldots,g_m \in k[x]$,
not necessarily in $k$.

Any comments are welcome; thank you!
Also asked in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4245950/a-variation-on-kx2-x3-kx) with no comments.

Comment: I don't right now have anything more to say, but if I think of more I will post an answer.

Comment: Actually, what I wrote is wrong. Let me write something more careful...

Comment: @WillSawin, thanks again. I am curious to see what you think holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such $F, G$ do exist, unless I missed a criterion.

One possibility is to take $F(T)$ a polynomial such that $F(h)$ is never zero, such as $T^3 + x^2$, and then $G(T) = x F(T)$. Then you can use the same $x = G(T)/F(T)$ trick.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please, what if we replace $x^2,x^3$ with any $f_0,g_0$ such that $k(f_0,g_0)=k(x)$?

Comment: @user237522 I'm not sure. The obvious generalization is to take a rational function in $f_0$ and $g_0$ representing $x$ and look for $F, G$ where the value of that function is independent of $T$, but this won't necessarily exist for an arbitrary rational function.

Comment: Thank you; yes, I also thought that that generalization may not work and wondered what could be said in that general case of $k(f_0,g_0)=k(x)$. Maybe I should have asked about the general case in the first place. Anyway, your comments are helpful.